SVM most important coefficient doesn't have dependency on target class
I've trained an SVM classifier with my data, looked at the coefficients and then plotted the most important training feature against my target class. However, I found there to be no dependency ( x axis is the class, y axis is the most important feature ). I trained the SVM on whether the class value is 0 or greater than 0 but the image shows all class values in my data set.

My code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import metrics, svm, preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

targetRaw = df[ target ]
correlationRaw = df[ mostImportantFeature ]

y = df[ target ]
X = df.drop( columns=[ target ] )

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size= 0.4 )

scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform( X_train )
X_test = scaler.fit_transform( X_test )

svc = svm.SVC( kernel='linear' )
svc.fit( X_train, y_train )
y_pred = svc.predict( X_test )
print( "Testing Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score( y_test, y_pred ) )

coefficients = 15

imp, names = zip( *sorted( zip( svc.coef_[ 0 ], X.columns.values ) ) )
plt.figure( 0 )
plt.xlabel( "Attribution" )
plt.ylabel( "Input Features" )
plt.barh( range( len( names[ -coefficients: ] ) ), imp[ -coefficients: ], align='center' )
plt.yticks( range( len( names[ -coefficients: ] ) ), names[ -coefficients: ] )
plt.savefig( 'SVMCoefficientsAttribution.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100 )

plt.figure( 1 )
plt.xlabel( target )
plt.ylabel( "Feature" )
plt.scatter( targetRaw.tolist(), correlationRaw.tolist(), s= 4.0 )
plt.savefig( 'SVMTargetFeatureCorrelation.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100 )


Unless I'm missing something, y needs to be binarized.
The class y, which you plotted on the x-axis of the chart, apparently has values like 0, 0, 0, 1.05, 1.12, etc. You wrote, "I trained the SVM on whether the class value is 0 or greater than 0", but I don't see that binarization in your code, for example with something like:
y = df[target] > 0

BTW, good that you are standardizing your data, but you should not fit a new scaler to the test set. Fit to & transform train, then use the same scaler to transform test (otherwise you are leaking info into test). Best idea is to put the scaler and the estimator into a pipeline, then you don't have to worry about it.
